# How do I hide / remove a ZFS dataset from the Nautilus left panel?

Tags: nautilus, 19.04, zfs

After installing Ubuntu 19.04, all of my zfs datasets (with mount points within my home folder) show up in the nautilus sidebar.  This didn't happen in 18.04.  Is there a way I can hide these?

[Screen Shot of Nautilus Sidebar with ZFS datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQeyy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2-zvol.rules`:

```
# ZFS volumes
KERNEL=="zd*", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

(from https://blog.vx.sk/archives/238 )

Comment: Just stumbled on my own answer, which I now see doesn't address the question. My answer applied to zvols, not to zfs datasets.